# build hector_quadrotor in fedora 18

Tags: hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello ROS es ..
I want to build an run hector_quadrotor stack and its [slam indoor demo] (http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor/Tutorials/Quadrotor%20indoor%20SLAM%20demo)
in Fedora .. I know that ros is more compatible with ubuntu .. I build ROS from source ..and now want to make hector as mentioned link , but i have problem ..
when i run catkin_make I get som error :

---

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "hardware_interface" with any of the following names:

    hardware_interfaceConfig.cmake
    hardware_interface-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "hardware_interface" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "hardware_interface_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "hardware_interface" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_controller/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

---

i know that i should resolve dependency and I run :
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y
but now i get these error :

---

```
hector_quadrotor_controller: No definition of [controller_interface] for OS version [spherical]
hector_quadrotor_teleop: No definition of [joy] for OS version [spherical]
hector_quadrotor_controller_gazebo: No definition of [gazebo_ros_control] for OS version [spherical]
```

---

i'm in Fedora 18 .. i'm sorry for that :!
but i should use this distro ..
please help me around these problem dears in ROS ...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196371/build-hector_quadrotor-in-fedora-18/) by [lordsairos](https://answers.ros.org/users/20642/lordsairos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These messages indicate that you have missing dependencies.

Since you're on Fedora, you'll want to go to the wiki page (`wiki.ros.org/package`) for each ROS package that you need, and check out the hydro version of each package into your workspace.

If a particular package isn't a ROS package, you'll need to find the equivalent package in Fedora and install it through the package manager (`yum`, if I remember properly)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lordsairos](https://answers.ros.org/users/20642/lordsairos/) on 2014-10-31**:
you are right dear Austin .. I should fetch dependency sources into src folder of my catkin work space, and rosdep update and install them using catkin_make . i think ROS has not a handy and standard route for building packages .. the user but not developers may get confused .. i'm trying.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-31**:
I haven't used it much, but I think the [rosinstall_generator](http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator) can help download the proper dependencies automatically.